# Changing indent of second line in Chapter heading

Tags: spacing

I'm currently using the book class to write a long document. Currently, when I have a long chapter it appears like this (not sure how to embed images):
[image]

I can make this look more the way I want by including the following code:

```
\usepackage{blindtext}


\makeatletter

\newif\ifusedot

\usedottrue

\newcommand{\UseDot}{%
\ifusedot
.%
\else
%
\fi
}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries\thechapter\UseDot\space 
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge\bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }
}

\makeatother
```

This produces this style of heading:

[image]

However, I want the 'to' and 'some' to line up in the heading, i.e I want 'to' to be indented to the right. Is there anyway to do this by re-defining the chapter heading above?

Cheers,

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format without the preceding **Chapter** line is actually close to the standard section heading layout so you could probably have used `\@startsection` like the lower level headings, but from where you are just use `\@hangfrom`

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\makeatletter

\newif\ifusedot

\usedottrue

\newcommand{\UseDot}{%
\ifusedot
.%
\else
%
\fi
}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
     \@hangfrom{\huge\bfseries\thechapter\UseDot\space}% 
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge\bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text.}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```