# Indent wrapped chapter title

Tags: chapters, titlesec

I want to indent the title block of my chapter heading. The code below is almost exactly how I want chapter titles displayed except for the fact that the second line and onward of the chapter title are aligned with the chapter number. How do I do this?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}    
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Large \thechapter\ \quad}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction }
\section{Motivation}
\end{document}
```

What I want[image: Desired identation]

Comment: Probably related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330796/134144

Comment: See also [sectioning - Indent for second line of chapter/section title - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271194/indent-for-second-line-of-chapter-section-title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple with the `linegoal` package:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Large \thechapter\ \quad\parbox[t]{\linegoal}}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction }
\section{Motivation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Leandriis comment is related. However I did it a different way after someone suggested using minipages:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}    
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Large \thechapter\ \quad}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\huge}% note that \bfseries has no effect with the default fonts
{\filright\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}
{0ex}
{\vspace{1ex}%
    \Large \begin{minipage}[t]{0.05\textwidth}\thechapter\end{minipage} \hspace{0.05\linewidth} \begin{minipage}[t]{.9\textwidth}}
    [\end{minipage}]

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction Introduction }
\section{Motivation}
\end{document}
```