# Formatting of chapter title in table of content and in document

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I am facing a specific requirement for the format of the table of contents.

I am using the book class.
Rather than `1 Introduction #` in the table of contents, the requirement is `Chapter 1: Introduction #` (in which # is the page number).

In the text, rather than `Chapter 1 (new line) Introduction` the requirement is `Chapter 1: Introduction`.

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

\section{My subsection title}
\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If your title is longer than one line, do you want hanging indentation?

Comment: Yes, that would be good, didn't think of that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version does not use additional packages.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \def\numberline##1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{\@chapapp~##1:\hfil}}%
      \advance\@tempdima by 4.5em
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2%
                                 \kern-\p@\kern\p@}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \interlinepenalty\@M
      \if@mainmatter
        \Huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter: #1\par\nobreak
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \else
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
      \fi
    \fi
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
  
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Abstract}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

\blindtext[1]

\chapter{A very very very very very very very very very long title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks John. This works! The only thing missing is the ":" in the TOC (Chapter 1: Introduction), but I don't think that will be problematic.

Comment: A more problematic issue is that all frontmatter (Abstract, Abbreviations etc) now has "Chapter" in front of it.

Comment: Moved \@chapapp to \numberline.  No number, no \chaptername.

Comment: This works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `book` class the following will do the trick:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}% <-- to change chapter, section,... style
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}% <-- changes to ToC
\usepackage{blindtext}

%rename \thechapter to easy display in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
%punctuation for chapters in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}
%Indentation for chapters in ToC
%separation between the colon and "Introduction" is given in the second argument. The indentation for the whole line is given in the first argument
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0ex}{13.5ex}

%Definition of the new chapter style
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\huge}{Chapter \thechapter :}{1ex}{}

%not sure if sections, subsections, etc. need an specific format
%this for example will change the output of sections
%\titleformat%
%{\section} %<-- command, this will modify section
%[hang] %<-- shape, for section it would be hang too
%{\Large\bfseries} %<-- format
%{\thesection} %<-- label, the number before the actual section name
%{1ex} %<-- horizontal separation between label and title
%{} %<-- code preceding the title body
%[after code] %<-- code following the title body


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

\section{My subsection title}
\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

to obtain a better indentation for long chapter titles you can see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491339/indent-wrapped-chapter-title)

Comment: Thanks Luis.. This adds "Chapter" to everything, including sections, subsections, etc. I would need only the chapter title to be modified. The added number is Roman (I,II,III), whereas I am looking for (1,2,3). (I have edited the MWE to by including a section).

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my code to do something closer to your needs

Comment: Thanks Luis, this works perfectly.

Comment: Glad this worked

Answer (score 1):

Use the `memoir` class (a superset of the `book` and `report` classes).

```
% chaptocstyleprob.tex  SE 567907

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%% styling the chapter titles
\makechapterstyle{yourstyle}{%
  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{: }
}

%% styling the chapter ToC entries
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{1.8em}
\renewcommand{\cftchaptername}{Chapter\space}
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{:}

\begin{document}
\chapterstyle{yourstyle} %% use your chapter style
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents  
%% or \tableofcontents* if you don't want the ToC listed in the ToC

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

\blindtext[1]

\setcounter{chapter}{11}

\chapter{Another chapter}

\end{document}
```

The `memoir` class provides many methods for changing the appearance of a document. Read the manual (`> texdoc memoir`) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I am using the book class, and have written a thesis in it. Switching to memoir now will be quite involved, I think.